# How to create VSTO Ribbon Gallery that looks like Excel "From Other Sources"?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto, ribbon

How do I create a Ribbon Gallery with buttons like the one in Excel, shown below? Specifically, I want to have the buttons with title and long descriptions, and icons by the side.

I am using VSTO C# and Winforms.

[image]

This is as far as I got:

[image]

Comment: Are you going to reward the bounty or do you miss something in the answer?

Comment: @MichielOvereem sorry about that. There was a specific time requirement before I could award the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studio 2010 (VSTO 4.0) this can be accomplished by using a Menu Control, and setting the Description of the child buttons of this menu. The bold text is the label, the long non-bold text is the description.

This only works when the Menu ItemSize is set to Large.

Comment: Where to find "Menu ItemSize"? I am editing from the VSTO Ribbon designer.

Comment: The control to start with should be Menu instead of Gallery.

Comment: Your right, I overlooked that you used a gallery. I've updated the answer.

Comment: nice,in contrast with the gallery control has nothing advantage.